# Angular PrimeNg: Not able to Sort columns

Tags: primeng, angular10, primeng-table

I would like to sort specific columns of a table using Angular PrimeNG component. I added the following code based on the documentation but isn't working as expected. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/table/sort

```
    <p-table [value]="tablename" [paginator]="true" [columns]="cols" [rows]="10">
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
        <th>Heading1</th>
        <th pSortableColumn="name">Heading2<p-sortIcon field="name"></p-sortIcon></th>
        <th pSortableColumn="duedate">Heading3<p-sortIcon field="duedate"></p-sortIcon></th>
        <th pSortableColumn="amount">Heading4 <p-sortIcon field="amount"></p-sortIcon></th>
        <th pSortableColumn="username">Heading5<p-sortIcon field="username"></p-sortIcon></th>
        <th>Heading6</th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Out of these 6 headers, I am performing a sort on 4 columns, some of them work as expected but some don't. I am not sure what I am missing here. Is it because of pagination? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show the JSON you are sending to the `p-table`. Your field names are suspect.

Comment: The table name is 'searchResults' which is an array of objects (populated from an API call that retrieves the data). Apologize for the confusion, the fields names are only for reference but in reality, they look something like this - 'name', 'duedate','canceleddate','companyname' etc.

Comment: So your actual code looks like `pSortableColumn="name"`, etc?

Comment: yes, I modified the code in the original post for a clear picture. Please check.

Comment: That looks correct. You mention that it works for some columns and not others - are anay errors produced when it doesn't work?

Comment: It works for fields such as 'duedate' and 'amount' (date and number fields) but doesn't work for 'name' and 'username' text. Doesn't show any errors because it does do something but it's just that the order isn't correct alphabetically. Also, when I click on sortable column in the subsequent pages- it always defaults to page 1.

Comment: Sounds like the real problem is the sort routine rather than the table setup. Check the PrimeNg documentation to see how to implement a custom sorter.